# Do I need a switch or router or ???/

Tags: networking, router, switch

Spectrum aka Time Warner, just "upgraded" me from a Thomson DWG875-X to a Ubee DDM3521. It took me some time to get it working since I guess the Ubee isn't a router and I had my Synology set to Bridge mode.

Anyway, the real problem is that the Synology router is not in the same room as the Ubee, and the Thomson had 4 ethernet ports off the back, one went to our TV and the other to the VOIP device. Without those ports I no longer have TV or phone.

So I need to buy something to make this work. This is what I think the network configuration would look like:

[image]

Now I think this is called a switch, but I'm not certain.

What do I need to buy to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What is the difference between a switch and a router?

A Switch only sends traffic between network ports, but does not assign IP Adresses and does not manage traffic in any other way.

A router can hand out ip adresses and can transport traffic between outbound and inbound connections.

Your UBEE device is only a modem and will only hand out 1 ip address.

If you add a switch at the ? all devices will have no idea what their IP configuration would be and thus things are not working correctly. In addition, connections made to the public ip address will halt at the modem because there's no way to know where such traffic is needed to go next.

So what you need is a Router, to create an internal network. The router has a DHCP server to assign IP Addresses, and can do NAT translation. NAT translation (or port forwarding) tells incoming traffic from the public IP where it needs to go.

That said, You could in theory also place the Synology router at the location of the ? and place a switch at the location where the synology is currently located, unless the synology also does WIFI, then the range can become a problem.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, the synology is also my wireless access point and is centrally located. There's way too much equipment hanging off of it (backup drives, NAS, printer) to consider moving it.